# How to make sticky headers with collection view layout (not flow layout) and UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to implement sticky headers in my collection view layout, but in a efficient way. I looked into the apple documentation and I found UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext.

I implemented this object along with my custom collection view layout. My  goal was to achieve not call `prepareLayout` when the collection view scrolls.

I coded the following in my custom collection view layout:

```
- (BOOL) shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds{
    return YES;
}

+ (Class)invalidationContextClass{
    return [InvalidationContext class];
}

- (void)invalidateLayoutWithContext:(UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext *)context{

    NSMutableArray * indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];

    NSInteger numberOfSections = self.collectionView.numberOfSections;

    for (NSInteger section = 0; section < numberOfSections; section++) {
        NSInteger numberOfItemsInSection = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];
        if (numberOfItemsInSection > 0) {
            [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section]];
        }
    }

    [context invalidateItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
    [super invalidateLayoutWithContext:context];
}
```

And this is my UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext subclass :

```
#import "InvalidationContext.h"

@implementation InvalidationContext

- (BOOL)invalidateEverything {
    return NO;
}

@end
```

**Someone can help me to discover what is wrong?**

**Note:** *My sticky headers are the first row for each section. I also was not enable to implement the headers with supplementary views.*

Comment: "implement the headers with supplementary views": that is the way to go. If you have problems, ask a new question therefore and show what you have done, what you expect and what is actually happening.

Comment: The problem is not clear at all. What was your concrete problem? As @shallowThought said, you could explain what you expected and what is actually happening.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, with supplementary view I could implement in a efficient way my custom collection view layout with sticky headers. If someone wants to see my code, feel free to ask it.

Comment: Downvote because this answer does not provide any useful information about the topic. You could at least explain what you did.